# How to update subscriber status of a subscriber in all subscribers present in a child BU using landing page present in other child BU using WSProxy?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpagesurl, wsproxy

I am trying to change a subscriber status in all subscribers from one child BU to other VIA cloud pages. I am trying to use impersonation method by using below code, but its not working ,Please suggest how can I use below code effectively.

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core",1);
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var accountId: YOURMID
prox.resetClientIds(); // resets current account id;
prox.setClientId({"ID": accountId}); // impersonates other BU
</script>
```